# Jupyter notebook: images embedded in markdown do not show up in pdf

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I am embedding some images in my markdown `notebook` cells by way of:

```
<img src=" C:\my\path\Pics\basic_coupled_inductors.png" height="20" width="550">
```

This renders OK in the `notebook` itself, and also gets properly translated when I save it to static HTML.

Thinks do not work if I try to convert to pdf:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf my_notebook.ipynb
```

The result is just text, no images.

How should I include my images in the notebook so that they both show when I am working on it, and when I create a PDF from it?